# Adding keyboard shortcuts for command prompt on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, command-line, keyboard-shortcuts

For command prompt I'd like to add keyboard shortcuts, that I cannot find in the properties or default windows.

The keyboard shortcuts I have in mind are:

- Ctrl+A for select all
- Ctrl+C for copy
- Ctrl+V for paste
- F8 for reset
- F11 for full screen

Comment: Not possible, but there are alternative keyboard shortcuts and methods. For example copy/paste goes through the right-mouse button menu, full screen = alt-enter.

Comment: If you turn on Quick Edit, you will get the copy/paste shortcuts. For anything else, I recommend switching to Cmder.

Comment: @JulianKnight well-done; put it as an answer

Comment: Realised I should have done that as soon as I pressed the add button :)

Comment: There are lots of command prompt alternatives with those features.

Answer (score 0):

If you turn on Quick Edit, you will get the copy/paste shortcuts. For anything else, I recommend switching to Cmder which provides an extended shell including macro's & multiple tabs.