# Creating a program shortcut that runs octave through cmder

Tags: shortcuts, octave, cmder

In response to a previous question ([Adding keyboard shortcuts for command prompt on Windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/897864/adding-keyboard-shortcuts-for-command-prompt-on-windows-7)) I asked on this site I am now using cmder instead of command prompt as it is more user-friendly (as it includes keyboard shortcuts like `Ctrl+C`, `Ctrl+V`, *etc.*) now I'd like to get other command-line programs (e.g., GNU Octave, Python, IPython, *etc.*) to run through it instead of cmd. I'd like to know how to create shortcuts with this capability, I have tried changing the program's target from the location of the program's exe file to the location of the cmder exe file with the location of the program's exe file immediately after it.

For example, for GNU  Octave I have tried:

```
C:\Users\Brenton\Programs\cmder\Cmder.exe C:\Software\Octave-3.6.4\bin\octave-3.6.4.exe
```

and its minor variants such as:

```
C:\Users\Brenton\Programs\cmder\Cmder.exe "C:\Software\Octave-3.6.4\bin\octave-3.6.4.exe"
```

along with:

```
cmder C:\Software\Octave-3.6.4\bin\octave-3.6.4.exe
```

(after adding cmder's location to my PATH environment variable)

and

```
cmder "C:\Software\Octave-3.6.4\bin\octave-3.6.4.exe"
```

with all four giving the same result, a blank Cmder window that does not contain Octave.

I know that Octave can be called from Cmder, though, as I have done it on this very same PC by opening Cmder and running `octave` after adding octave's location to my PATH variable too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cmder.exe` do not pass any arguments to ConEmu at all.

You need to run ConEmu directly without using that wrapper. Read about ConEmu [switches](http://conemu.github.io/en/ConEmuArgs.html).

Smth like this:

```
ConEmu.exe -LoadCfgFile "full path to conemu.xml" -cmd "C:\Software\Octave-3.6.4\bin\octave-3.6.4.exe"
```

Comment: I don't understand the XML file input. Where do I find this file or do I have to make it? If I have to make it how do I do this, keeping in mind I haven't the foggiest as to the syntax of XML files.

Comment: Nvm I experimented omitting the part I didn't understand of your code (i.e., `LoadCfgFile "full path to conemu.xml"`) after adding the location of ConEmu64.exe on my PC to my PATH variable and got what I wanted. Namely this is my current shortcut target: `ConEmu64 -cmd C:\Software\Octave-3.6.4\bin\octave.exe`

Answer (score 2):

To run Octave CLI through the beautiful cmder, this is what I did as mentioned by [Maximus](https://superuser.com/users/139371/maximus) - author of ConEmu in [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/482325/change-conemus-default-start-directory/482340#482340):

- Check "Force ConEmu as default terminal for console applications
- add octave-cli.exe in list of hooked executable

Apply and save settings as shown in image below.

Finally open cmder and type octave-cli and viola you have octave in cmder!

[image: Snapshot of settings dialogbox of cmder]
[image: Octave in cmder snapshot]